# update gradle from 4.4 to 5.4 make joda-time dependancy issue

Tags: gradle, compiler-errors, dependencies, jodatime

HI I've migrated a project to gradle version 5.4 from 4.4. Since then `gradlew build` returns error as below.

`....ConvTable.java:6: error: package org.joda.time does not exist
import org.joda.time.DateTime;`

`...ConvetService.java:5: error: package org.joda.time does not exist
import org.joda.time.DateTime;`

`...ConvetService.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  ConvTableP getLastCononTableDate(String fromCurrency, String toCurrency, DateTime dateTimeZone) throws IOException;`

`symbol:   class DateTime
 location: interface ConvetService
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details`

`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cur-api:compileJava'`

gradle file looks like below. and its a sub project of bigger one

```
apply plugin: "j-library" 
apply plugin: "m-publish" 

group = "com.t.cur" 

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 

publishing { publications { mavenJava(MavenPublication) { } } 

repositories { 
  maven { url "${mv_repo_url}" } } 
} 

dependencies { 
  implementation "com.t.com:x-core:1.0.0" 
  implementation "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6" 
}
```

Comment: Some context would help. What does your build.gradle file look like?

Comment: @BjørnVester updated the question with more gradle file content. x-core uses this joda-time library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that as part of the upgrade, you changed `compile` configurations with `implementation`. One of the differences with the new configuration is that the dependencies will not be exposed to consuming projects as part of the compilation classpath. The idea is that the dependencies you put into `implementation` are implementation specific and should not "leak" onto the consuming projects. This speeds up the build when using incremental compilation as dependent classes are only recompiled if the public API changes but not the internal implementation. There is also a case to be made for providing looser coupling between projects, though this is a bit more subjective. The `implementation` dependencies will still be part of, and resolved, in the `runtimeClasspath` configuration though.

So (assuming this is the underlying issue of cause), the dependency `x-core` used to provide Joda as a transitive dependency for compilation. But this is no longer the case.

There are two ways to fix it. If you use Joda as part of the public API of `x-core`, you need to declare it using the `api` configuration instead of `implementation` (and use the `java-library` plugin if you don't already). This will make Joda part of the compilation classpath of dependent projects.

On the other hand, if this sub-project just happens to use Joda as well, but in a completely unrelated way to `x-core`, you should declare it as dependency here as well (either as `implementation` or `api` using the same rules as before).

Comment: Thanks Bjørn Vester, as you guess that what exactly happened. I'll try to fix the issue as you suggested.